# How to add sequelize association?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

So i have two models - One is User and other is Wallet. Now, the association is - user hasOne Wallet !

Am using sequelize cli to create model and migration, so when i created a new model named Wallet - it generated a model & migration file, Now how to add association ? Should i need to add both hasOne and belongs to ?

This is my migration file of Wallet :

```
await queryInterface.createTable('Wallets', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      balance: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      userType: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
```

I have manually added userId, ( is this needs to be manually added or it will be automatically created when sync ? )

This is my User Model code:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      
    }
  };
  User.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },  
    phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
```

In this code, there is `static associate(models) {    }` How to add association to this ? Or how actually association needs to be done between user and Wallet ?

Comment: check out this blog you will know how to add association https://medium.com/@andrewoons/how-to-define-sequelize-associations-using-migrations-de4333bf75a7

Comment: and https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html